# Need help with an incremental amount picker with a min/max amount

Tags: selection, checkout

I am designing a point selector that only allows incremental selections, let's say by 10s, and has a min and max amount that can be selected. See the image below.

[image]

UPDATE: This turned out to test pretty well...

[image]

Comment: Do you not want to use actual labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there any reason not to be explicit and just show them?

What's the ranges we're talking about? If if it's large, you could also make the numbers into an active input field, and use some helper text to keep increments divisible by 10.

I'm not sure if the arrow in the 2nd version is clear; just trying to think of another approach.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe8BlY.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Min/Max will be translated into a bunch of different language, hence wanting to steer clear of words. Arrow is confusing. The ranges all depend on the purchase amount and how many rewards a buyer might have available. Could be many steps. I think I actually have a good solve for it.

Comment: Also, thank you so much for your time in answering this!